# Can't install Composer from Symfony2 official page on windows 8

Tags: php, symfony

I'm beginer with Symfony2 Framework and php. I have started doing a SF2 tutorial and i stopped on setting up the project. I can't install Composer from SF official page on Windows 8, when i choose a php.exe from my php file and click install, then i see following error:

*Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl*

I'm working with WebServ 2.1. I have added to php.ini DEVELOPMENT following code

```
extension_dir = C:\WebServ\php\ext
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

C:\WebServ\php\ext is a path to folder with extension files and it contain php_openssl.dll.

It still doesn't work. Do anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Print phpinfo() and make sure SSL is present there.
Don't forget to restart the webserver after editing php.ini